# AsyncTask, JSON parsing and OnClickListener in one class

Tags: android, json, multithreading, android-asynctask, onclicklistener

I have an activity, where I have a class extending AsyncTask for HTTP GET request and parse then a data, which I get. 
Problem is simple - onclick doesn't working.

Here is a part of my code:

```
public class GetMethod extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls){                        
              BufferedReader in = null;

              for (String url : urls) {
                  HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                    String l = "";
                    String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                    while ((l = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(l + nl);
                    }
                    in.close();
                    data = sb.toString();

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                             public void run() {
                                 JSONObject jObject;
                        try {
                            jObject = new JSONObject(data);

                            //JSONObject object = jObject.getJSONObject("pharms");
                            JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("pharms");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                            name = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name").toString();
                            phone = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("phone").toString();
                            latitude = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("latitude").toString();
                            longitude = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("longitude").toString();
                            address = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("address").toString();

                            RelativeLayout ll2 = new RelativeLayout(context);
                            //ll2.setOrientation(Orientation.ho)

                            *** Create button named call ***
                            call.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                      Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                                        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
                                        startActivity(callIntent);    //// This function doesn't work
                                }
                            });
                            ll2.addView(call);
                            *** Create textview named tv ***
                            ll2.addView(tv);

                            ll.addView(ll2);
                        }  
                        }
```

Comment: You should not do the UI related operations in the doInBackground as its runs asynchronously of the main thread and updates the UI. So its always better to do the UI operations in `onPostExecute()` method besides in `doInBackground()`. Just parse your Json in doInbackground and then update your UI in onPostExecute.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what's going on. If you are using an AsyncTask, it's not obvious from the code.

AsyncTask and other background thread operations should be *background-only* except in rare situations. They're meant to be asynchronous; while the background thread is doing its work, the user goes off to do something else or waits for a moment. Trying to manipulate the UI from the background usually doesn't work out right.

If you're doing a HTTP GET request, you should let it parse the JSON into persistent storage, and then come back to the foreground when it's done. Then you can act on the data. Remember, too, that an AsyncTask is cancelled if the Activity needs to be recreated. If the user accidentally drops the device, it may go from portrait to landscape mode and destroy your AsyncTask before it's finished. It might be better to use an IntentService, which will keep running.

I can't say for certain, since I don't know what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Try to explain what I'm doing. I have a server with data on it. Data is, for example, list of pharmacies with name, phone, address etc. By GET request I get this data and parse it with JSON. It works. It didn't work until I add this:
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                         public void run() 

Then for every item of array I create TextView and Button. In TextView name and phone. When user will press the button, it will be call on this phone. And OnClick on these buttons doesn't work